# Hofstadter H-sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, recursion

## Definition

- \$a(0) = 0\$
- \$a(n) = n-a(a(a(n-1)))\$ for integer \$n > 0\$

## Task

Given non-negative integer \$n\$, output \$a(n)\$.

## Testcases

```
n     a(n)
0     0
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     4
6     4
7     5
8     5
9     6
10    7
11    7
12    8
13    9
14    10
15    10
16    11
17    12
18    13
19    13
20    14
10000 6823
```

## References

- [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HofstadterH-Sequence.html)
- [OEIS A005374](https://oeis.org/A005374)

Comment: Related challenges about Hofstadter sequences: [1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/86880/8478), [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80608/8478), [3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37529/8478)

Comment: And I still think you should reference GEB...

Comment: How is [tag:number-theory] relevant here?

Comment: @flawr *facepalm*  Let me try that again: [Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach)

Comment: @StigHemmer Actually facepalm has its own Emoji now: [](http://emojipedia.org/face-palm/)

Answer (score 20):

### Haskell, <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```hs
f 0=0
f n=n-f(f$f$n-1)
```

Simply uses the definition of the sequence. `f(f$f$n-1)` is equivalent to `f (f (f (n-1)))`.

Test:

```hs
main = putStrLn . show $ map f [0..20]
-- => [0,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10,11,12,13,13,14]
```

Thanks to [Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39242/anders-kaseorg) for a byte!

Comment: `(f$f$f$n-1)` = `f(f$f$n-1)` saves a byte.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
’ßßßạµṠ¡
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZw5_Dn8Of4bqhwrXhuaDCoQ&input=&args=MjA) or [verify the smaller test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZw5_Dn8Of4bqhwrXhuaDCoQowcjIwwrXFvMOH4oKsRw&input=).

#### How it works

```
’ßßßạµṠ¡  Main link. Argument: n

     µṠ¡  Execute the preceding chain sign(n) times.
’         Decrement n, yielding n - 1.
 ßßß      Recursively call the main link thrice.
    ạ     Take the absolute difference of n and the result.
```

Comment: Can the Jelly parser even handle programs larger than 10 bytes?

Answer (score 9):

## J, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
-$:^:3@<:^:*
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @[Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun).

Computes the result by calling itself recursively when *n* > 0 three times on *n*-1 and subtracting that result from *n*. There is a different situation for the base case when *n* = 0. There it computes *n*-*n* which equals 0.

```
a(n) = n - n = 0           if n = 0
       n - a(a(a(n-1)))    if n > 0
```

[Try it here.](http://tryj.tk)

### Explanation

```
-$:^:3@<:^:*  Input: n
           *  Get the sign of n (n = 0 => 0, n > 0 => 1)
         ^:   Execute that many times
                (0 times means it will just be an identity function)
       <:       Decrement n
 $:             Call itself recursively
   ^:3          three times
      @         on n-1
-             Subtract that result from n and return
```

Comment: I don't think the parentheses are needed.

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica, 20 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 (or compatible) encoding and `$CharacterEncoding` set to a matching value, like the Windows default `WindowsANSI`.

```
±0=0
±n_:=n-±±±(n-1)
```

This defines a unary operator `±`.

Comment: Would you explain what ± does or how it works?  Btw, congrats on 100k.

Comment: @DavidC Thanks. :) It's just a built-in operator which is shorthand for the unused function `PlusMinus`. See [this post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82740/8478) for details.

Comment: Very interesting. Dispenses with the `@` or `[ ]` too.

Answer (score 6):

## Julia, 16 bytes

```julia
!n=n>0&&n-!!!~-n
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IW49bj4wJiZuLSEhIX4tbgoKZm9yIG4gaW4gMDoyMAogICAgQHByaW50ZigiJTJ1ICUydVxuIiwgbiwgIW4pCmVuZA&input=)

#### How it works

We redefine the unary operator `!` for our purposes.

If **n = 0**, the comparison `n>0` returns *false* and so does `!`.

Otherwise, the code after `&&` gets executed. `~-n` is equivalent to `(n-1)` in two's complement, `!!!` recursively calls `!` thrice on **n - 1**, and the resulting value is subtracted from **n**.

Comment: Mind adding an explanation? I have no idea what is going on with `-!!~-` ._.

Comment: Nothing fancy. `!` is simply the function's name.

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 31 bytes

```python
a=lambda n:n and n-a(a(a(n-1)))
```

Recursion limit and time constraints make above function impractical, but in theory it should work (and does work for small n).

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```
n=>[0,...Array(n)].reduce((p,_,i,a)=>a[i]=i-a[a[p]])
```

I could have been boring and written the recursive version but this version is much faster (easily coping with the last test case) and also uses `reduce` so that's a plus!

Answer (score 4):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/), <s>49</s> 43 bytes

```
.+
$*1:
{`^1(1*):
$1:::-1$1
}`^:*(1*)-\1

1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCoxOgp7YF4xKDEqKToKJDE6OjotMSQxCn1gXjoqKDEqKS1cMQoKMQ&input=MTA)

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*Thanks to Dennis for saving 1 byte.*

```
ri0{_(jjj-}j
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri0%7B_(jjj-%7Dj&input=20)

Comment: That works for surprisingly high values. I think you don't need the `a`.

Comment: @Dennis Oh, that's good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
a=function(n)ifelse(n<1,0,n-a(a(a(n-1))))
```

Usage:

```
> a(1)
1
> a(10)
7
```

This recursive approach doesn't scale well for larger values of `n` though.

Comment: You should be able to lose a byte (and a number of errors w/ bad inputs) if you change your condition to `n<1`. As its a sequence, it is only really defined for non-negative integers anyhow.

Comment: `a=function(n)"if"(n,n-a(a(a(n-1))),0)` will work for several bytes off.

Answer (score 3):

## [Oasis](http://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 6 bytes

Code:

```
nbaa-0
```

Expanded version:

```
a(n) = nbaa-
a(0) = 0
```

Code:

```
n      # Push n
 b     # Calculate a(n - 1)
  a    # Calculate a(a(n - 1))
   a   # Calculate a(a(a(n - 1)))
    -  # Subtract a(a(a(n - 1))) from n
```

[Try it online!](http://oasis.tryitonline.net/#code=bmJhYS0w&input=&args=MjA)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```apl
{⍵=0:0⋄⍵-∇⍣3⊢⍵-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR71ZbAyuDR90tQJbuo472R72LjR91LQLxDGv/pz1qm/Cot@9R31RP/0ddzYfWGz9qmwjkBQc5A8kQD8/g/2mHVhjoPOrdbGoKAA)

Surprisingly, there's no APL answer to this challenge. This is a literal implementation of the function in the OP.

TIO times out for \$n>90\$.

Saved a byte thanks to @Zacharý.

Comment: `{⍵=0:0⋄⍵-∇⍣3⊢⍵-1}`

Comment: `{×⍵:⍵-∇⍣3⊢⍵-1⋄0}` for 16.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), <s>58</s> 55 bytes

```
0000000: 16e0d7 bdcdf8 8cdf1b e6cfbb 840d3f bf659b 38e187  ..............?.e.8..
0000015: f8639b 39dc37 fc893f 666c05 7e7ed9 b88b3f ae0d3f  .c.9.7..?fl.~~...?..?
000002a: 676ed8 bd9940 7fdc3b 36619e f1                    gn...@..;6a..
```

Handles inputs up to **400** reasonably well, but run time increases dramatically after that point.

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=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&input=MjA) Check *Debug* to see the generated SBIN code.

#### Sesos assembly

The binary file above has been generated by assembling the following SASM code.

```lisp
set numin, set numout

get
jmp
    jmp
        rwd 3, add 1, rwd 1, add 1, fwd 4, sub 1
    jnz
    rwd 3, sub 1
jnz
rwd 3, add 1, fwd 2
jmp
    rwd 1, sub 1, fwd 3, sub 1, fwd 2, add 3
    jmp
        rwd 2
        jmp
            rwd 3
        jnz
        fwd 6, get, rwd 4, sub 1
        jmp
            fwd 1, sub 1
            jmp
                rwd 3
            jnz
            sub 1
            jmp
                fwd 3
            jnz
            rwd 4, sub 1
        jnz
        fwd 1
        jmp
            rwd 1, add 1, fwd 1, add 1
        jnz
        sub 1, fwd 3, sub 1
        jmp
            fwd 3
        jnz
        rwd 1, sub 1
    jnz
    rwd 2, get
    nop
        rwd 3
    jnz
    fwd 3, get, rwd 2
    jmp
        fwd 2, add 1
        jmp
            fwd 3
        jnz
        rwd 1, add 1, rwd 2
        jmp
            rwd 3
        jnz
        fwd 1, sub 1
    jnz
    fwd 2
    jmp
        rwd 2, add 1, fwd 2, sub 1
    jnz
    nop
        get, fwd 3
    jnz
    rwd 1, add 1, fwd 2
jnz
rwd 2, sub 1
jmp
    rwd 1, sub 1, fwd 1, sub 1
jnz
rwd 1, put
```

Answer (score 2):

## LISP, 61 bytes

```
(defun H(N)(if(= N 0)(return-from H 0)(- N(H(H(H(- N 1)))))))
```

Probably not the optimal solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <del>35</del> 32 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @PeterTaylor!*

```c
a(n){return n?n-a(a(a(n-1))):0;}
```

[Try it on Ideone!](https://ideone.com/8O5mPR)

Comment: In C you can use an integer directly as a conditional, giving a three-byte saving: `a(n){return n?n-a(a(a(n-1))):0;}`

Comment: @betseg - You have an erroneous `:` in your code too. You should take out the one after `?`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 42 bytes

```
int c(int n){return n>0?n-c(c(c(n-1))):0;}
```

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/KFLVfm)

```
class Main{
  static int c(int n){
    return n > 0
              ? n - c(c(c(n-1)))
              : 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
      System.out.println(i + ": " + c(i));
    }
    System.out.println("1000: " + c(1000));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 4
6: 4
7: 5
8: 5
9: 6
10: 7
11: 7
12: 8
13: 9
14: 10
15: 10
16: 11
17: 12
18: 13
19: 13
20: 14
 (last case takes too long..)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

The obvious implementation.

```ruby
a=->n{n<1?0:n-a[a[a[n-1]]]}
```

This is a longer, faster answer that caches previous entries in the sequence.
Both answers only work for versions after 1.9, as that was when `->`, the stabby lambda, was introduced to Ruby.

```ruby
->n{r=[0];i=0;(i+=1;r<<i-r[r[r[i-1]]])while i<n;r[n]}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 35 bytes

```
int a(int n)=>n>0?n-a(a(a(n-1))):0;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript, <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
~[0]{....,(===\.,@-+}@*)\;
~[0]{...)\;==\.,@-+}@*)\;
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=flswXXsuLi4pXDs9PVwuLEAtK31AKilcOw&input=MTAwMDA)

Locally `10000` takes less than half a second.

Answer (score 1):

## Maple, <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
`if`(n=0,0,n-a(a(a(n-1))))
```

Usage:

```
> a:=n->ifelse(n=0,0,n-a(a(a(n-1))));
> seq(a(i),i=0..10);
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6, 22 bytes

```
a=n=>n&&n-a(a(a(n-1)))
```

I'll be boring and do the recursive version :P

Answer (score 1):

### VBA, 69 bytes

```
Function H(N):ReDim G(N):For j=1To N:G(j)=j-G(G(G(j-1))):Next:H=G(N)
```

Works in the blink of an eye on the test set, slows down a little above n=1000000, runs into a memory wall a little above n=25 million.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
L-WbbyFtb3
```

Defines a function `y`. Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L-WbbyFtb3%0Ay20&debug=0)

This uses a relative new feature of Pyth. You can apply a function multiple times using the fold-syntax. It doesn't actually save any bytes, I used it just for demonstration purposes.

#### Explanation:

```
L-WbbyFtb3
L            define function y(b), that returns:
    b           b
 -Wb            and subtract the following if b>0
     yF  3      y applied three times to
       tb       b - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 34 bytes

```
dsn[zdddd1-;a;a;a-r:aln!=L]dsLx;ap
```

Input is taken from the top of the stack. This must be the only item on the stack, because the stack depth is used as a counter. Example of usage:

```
$ dc
10000dsn[zdddd1-;a;a;a-r:aln!=L]dsLx;ap
```

This is a fairly straightforward implementation of the sequence definition:

```
dsn               # Store n as `n', and keep a copy as a depth buffer (see below)
[                 # Open loop definition
 z                # Push stack depth i for i-th term
 dddd             # Duplicate stack depth four times, for a total of five copies
 1-               # Get i-1 for use as index to previous term
                  #   Note that if we hadn't duplicated n above, or left something else
                  #   on the stack, 0-1 would be -1, which is not a valid array index
 ;a;a;a           # Fetch a(a(a(i-1)))
 -                # Calculate i-a(a(a(i-1)))
 r                # Arrange stack to store i-th term: TOS |  i  (i-a(a(a(i-1))))
 :a               # Store i-th term in array `a'
 ln!=L            # Load n. If n!=i, we're not done calculating terms yet, so execute loop
]                 # Close loop definition. Note that we started with five copies of i:
                  #   i-1 was used to get last term
                  #   i-a(...) was used to calculate current term
                  #   ... i :a was used to store current term
                  #   i ln !=L was used to check loop exit condition
                  # One copy of i is left on the stack to increment counter
dsLx              # Duplicate loop macro, store it, and execute copy
;a                # Last i stored on stack from loop will equal n, so use this to get a(n)
p                 # Print a(n)
```

Anyways, it started out straightforward...then the golfing happened.

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 44 bytes

```lisp
(defun f(x)(if(= x 0)0(- x(f(f(f(1- x)))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc5LCsMwDEXReVbhoTQo@DnpJ4OuJonAEEJoU/DuXdNA0bMmviDQmdb83muVebHPFkyKSjZ5hhKiRrmEIvYbtK@er8r@ytsh1la0@wd8JB@9j8HH1cfNx93Hw8dIR5lABhACpAAxQA4QBCQBUUCW1Cz1Cw)

Answer (score 1):

### C++ ( MSVC, mainly )

#### Normal version : 40 bytes

```cpp
int a(int n){return n?n-a(a(a(n-1))):0;}
```

#### Template meta programming version : 130 bytes

```cpp
#define C {constexpr static int a(){return
template<int N>struct H C N-H<H<H<N-1>::a()>::a()>::a();}};template<>struct H<0>C 0;}};
```

Usage :

```cpp
std::cout << a(20) << '\n';       // Normal version
std::cout << H<20>::a() << '\n';  // Template version
```

The template version is the fastest code, since there's nothing faster than moving a value into a register => with optimization, `H<20>::a()` compile as :

```cpp
mov esi, 14
```

For 10000, the recursive version crashes due to a stack overflow error, and the template version crashes at compile time due to template instantiation depth. GCC goes to 900 ( 614 )

Comment: I think you don't need the space between `C` and `{` in the template meta programming version

Comment: @Zacharý MSVC refuses to compile without that space

Comment: Ahh, I see now why that seems to keep happening

Comment: @Zacharý It depends on the type of macro. If it has parameters, then i can remove the space, but here it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
©aßßßUÉ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=qWHf399VyQ==&input=OA==) or [run all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=qWHf399VyQ==&input=MjEKLW0=) (throws an overflow error for 10000)

Answer (score 1):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 36 bytes

```d
T a(T)(T n){return n?n---n.a.a.a:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcMxDoAgDADAWV7RsR0wxFEGP8EHSGBoosUg6kB8e9VcLqkGiBgIAwj1mttZBWQRa62M8Tc7/@hVOMEWWZCgm4G3vdQGR0vjl4s3w1255VUw4uSIvHn0BQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 72 bytes

```python
def f(n):
    a=[0];i=0
    while n:i+=1;a+=[i-a[a[a[i-i]]]];n-=1
    return a[i]
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/Q32qge)

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 56 bytes

```
$a={$n=$args[0];if($n){$n-(&$a(&$a(&$a($n-1))))}else{0}}
```

The PowerShell equivalent of a lambda to form the recursive definition. Execute it via the `&` call operator, e.g. `&$a(5)`. Takes a *long* time to execute -- even `50` on my machine (a recent i5 with 8GB RAM) takes around 90 seconds.

#### Faster iterative solution, 59 bytes

```
param($n)$o=,0;1..$n|%{$o+=$_-$o[$o[$o[$_-1]]]};$o[-1]*!!$n
```

Longer only because we need to account for input `0` (that's the `*!!$n` at the end). Otherwise we just iteratively construct the array up to `$n`, adding a new element each time, and output the last one at the end `$o[-1]`. Super-speedy -- calculating `10000` on my machine takes about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 55+2 = 57 bytes

```
^~n;
.~-]{:0$
v>1-}32[
v/  /:1-32[
>$:?/$~]{:0$.
/30@2[
```

The input is expected to be present on the stack at program start, so +2 bytes for the `-v` flag. [Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=Xn5uOwoufi1dezowJAp2PjEtfTMyWwp2LyAgLzoxLTMyWwo-JDo_LyR-XXs6MCQuCi8zMEAyWw&input=&args=LXYgNg)

This is hecka slow, as it uses recursion to calculate the result. Using TIO, `h(50)` takes over a minute. It returns the correct results <= 30, so I'm confident it would work for `h(10000)`, I just haven't run it to find out!

Answer (score 0):

## RETURN, 17 bytes

```
[$[$1-aaa-][]?]=a
```

<kbd>[Try it here!](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

Recursive operator that leaves result on the stack. Example usage:

```
[$[$1-aaa-][]?]=a 4a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```python
a=r,=0,
exec'r=len(a)-a[a[r]];a+=r,;'*input()
print r
```

Not even close to the recursive solution, but at least it's fast.

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/hVmuzw).

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 156 bytes

Mine is going to be a bit longer than the other C# answer, but my version can compute up to 10,000 (and higher) without a stack overflow, and can do all integers from 0 to 10,000 in a fraction of a second due to addition of a dictionary.  Most of the answers here can take hours to do integers in the thousands, so my extra bytes also lead to massive speed increases.

## Golfed

```
Dictionary<int,int> l=new Dictionary<int,int>();int H(int n){int v;if(n==0)return 0;if(l.TryGetValue(n,out v)){}else{v=n-H(H(H(n-1)));l.Add(n,v);}return v;}
```

## Ungolfed (with test program)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HH
{
    class Program
    {
        static Dictionary<int, int> l = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        static int H(int n)
        {
            int v;
            if (n == 0)
                return 0;
            if (l.TryGetValue(n, out v))
            { }
            else
            {
                v = n - H(H(H(n - 1)));
                l.Add(n, v);
            }
            return v;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, H(i));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: The other C# answer can't compute H(10,000) without a stack overflow, mine can print all numbers from H(1) to H(1,000,000) in a few seconds.  H(1,000,000) is 682,328 if anyone was wondering :P

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
(fn f[n](if(= 0 n)0(- n(f(f(f(dec n)))))))
```

So sad this is sorter than `(fn f[n](if(= 0 n)0(- n((comp f f f dec)n))))`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
L?b-byyytb0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38c@STepsrKyJMngf2Xgf0NjAA)

The program defines a lambda function.

The link adds `yQ` for I/O

Answer (score 0):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
0|-₁↰↰↰-↙?ȧ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qGXqo8451eVKCrp2Ckrl9o/aNjxqanq4q1Ox9lHX0v8GNbqPmhpBgmCk@6htpv2J5f//AwA)

10000 times out and I've not yet been able to verify it, nor do I expect to.

```
0|             The input and output are 0, or the input
  -₁           minus 1
    ↰          passed through this same predicate
     ↰         passed through this same predicate
      ↰        passed through this same predicate
       -↙?     minus the input
          ȧ    has an absolute value equal to the output.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 21 bytes

```
~{.{.(a a a-}{}if}:a~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v65ar1pPI1EBCHVrq2sz02qtEuv@/zcAAA)

```
~                      # Parse input to a number
 {               }:a   # Assign this function to the variable a
  .                    # Copy the number
   {        }{}if      # If it is bigger than 0 execute the first block, if it is 0 execute the second
    .(                 # Copy the number and decrement
      a a a            # a(a(a( n-1 )))
           -           # Subtract from the original number
                    ~  # Execute a
```

If the number is 0 nothing happens because there is already a 0 on top of the stack and we use that as the answer.